# Extract e-mail address from string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table called `Entities` with the column `CustomData`.

I need to extract the email address from each row.
Also if value is null I need to to show as null.

Sample rows from `CustomData`:

```
Id      CustomData                                                                                                                                                                                      Name
273     [{"Name":"Customer","Value":"test customer"},{"Name":"Address","Value":null},{"Name":"Email","Value":null},{"Name":"Company Name","Value":null},{"Name":"Other Phone","Value":null}]            2323123213
274     [{"Name":"Customer","Value":"Cash Sale"},{"Name":"Address","Value":null},{"Name":"Email","Value":"test@outlook.com"},{"Name":"Company Name","Value":null},{"Name":"Other Phone","Value":null}]  2222222222
```

This is the string i will be using to update my system.

I have previously achieved selecting the phone number form this same data but it was a fixed length. I can't seem to pull the e-mail address.

I will post a couple of the different methods I have tried so far once im back at my PC

Comment: Hi, what have you tried writing yourself? `SELECT [???????????] FROM [Entities] WHERE [Id]=@entityId` doesn't really seem like an attempt.

Comment: Yet another example of why you don't store delimited values in one column.

Comment: I know nothing about this project, but your question inspired me to look and I found this:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1000953/JSON-for-SQL-Server-Part.

Comment: Please google and learn about PATINDEX() and SUBSTRING() in sql.   The rest is a simple matter of programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, in such a denormalized data your only option is to parse it and try to get email. Most elegant way - is to use json parser, but it is not awailable in current versions of sql server, so you have to parse it manually.

Assuming each record for email starts with `{"Name":"Email","Value":`, you can do it in a few steps:

1. Find position of `{"Name":"Email","Value":` in your string.
2. Find first occurence of `}` in the right remainder of the string.
3. Get substring in between.
4. Check if it is string equals to 'null' - then return null, otherwise return string itself.

So it can be done like in this snippet:

```
declare @data nvarchar(max), @pattern nvarchar(max)

select @data = '[{"Name":"Customer","Value":"test customer"},
                 {"Name":"Address","Value":null},
                 {"Name":"Email","Value":null},
                 {"Name":"Company Name","Value":null},
                 {"Name":"Other Phone","Value":null}]'

select @pattern = '{"Name":"Email","Value":'

select nullif(substring(@data, 
             charindex(@pattern, @data, 0) + len(@pattern),
             charindex('}', @data, charindex(@pattern, @data, 0)) 
                - charindex(@pattern, @data, 0) - len(@pattern)
             ), 'null')
```